# Как посчитать количество всех диапазонов дат?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Есть таблица: id (int), user_id (int), start_time (timestamp), end_time (timestamp).

Нужно посчитать количество записей во всех диапазонах за указанную дату. Например, есть такой сет данных:

| ID | USER_ID | START_TIME | END_TIME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 2023-09-15 13:11:22.143 | 2023-09-15 13:12:22.143 |
| 3 | 1 | 2023-09-15 13:11:22.143 | 2023-09-15 13:12:22.143 |
| 4 | 1 | 2023-09-15 13:11:22.143 | 2023-09-15 13:12:22.143 |
| 5 | 1 | 2023-09-15 13:11:22.143 | 2023-09-15 13:12:22.143 |
| 6 | 1 | 2023-09-15 13:11:22.143 | 2023-09-15 13:12:22.143 |
| 7 | 1 | 2023-09-15 13:11:22.143 | 2023-09-15 13:12:22.143 |
| 8 | 1 | 2023-09-15 13:11:22.143 | 2023-09-15 13:13:22.143 |
| 9 | 1 | 2023-09-15 13:11:22.143 | 2023-09-15 13:13:22.143 |
| 10 | 1 | 2023-09-15 13:11:22.143 | 2023-09-15 13:13:22.143 |
| 11 | 1 | 2023-09-15 13:11:22.143 | 2023-09-15 13:14:22.143 |

Тут мы видим диапазоны:

- с 2023-09-15 13:11 до 2023-09-15 13:12 - 6 раз
- с 2023-09-15 13:11 до 2023-09-15 13:13 - 3 раза
- с 2023-09-15 13:11 до 2023-09-15 13:14 - 1 раза

Получается, чтобы ответить на вопрос: в какое время находилось одновременно максимальное число пользователей - нужно сказать **10 человек в период с 2023-09-15 13:11 до 2023-09-15 13:12**, так как до 12 минут было 6, до 13 еще 3 и до 14 минут еще 1, то есть все они были одновременно.

Уточнение, поле end_time может быть NULL, что означает, то пользователь не вышел из системы.

На вход в запрос/функцию приходит только дата, путь будет 2023-09-15.

Если записать такой запрос:

```sql
SELECT  
    *,
    COUNT(*) OVER (
        PARTITION BY start_time
        ORDER BY start_time
    )
```

то, если добавить строки в бд, например start_time=2023-09-15 13:09:22.143 и end_time=2023-09-15 13:12:22.143, эти значения не учитываются, хотя, это пользователь был в сети в диапазон даты 2023-09-15 13:11 до 2023-09-15 13:12.

Comment: MySQL или PostgreSQL? это разные СУБД. Удалите лишний тег. И точную версию не забудьте указать...

Comment: Ну вообще задача решается так. Валим все даты в кучу, добавляя к каждой вес - +1 для входа и -1 для выхода. И считаем сумму с накоплением с сортировкой по времени... а затем просто берём максимум этой суммы.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT timepoint
FROM ( SELECT timepoint, SUM(weight) OVER (ORDER BY timepoint) weight
       FROM ( SELECT start_time timepoint, 1 weight FROM table
              UNION ALL
              SELECT end_time, -1 FROM table
              ) timepoints
       GROUP BY 1
       ) weights
ORDER BY weight DESC LIMIT 1
```

Для ускорения можно сперва посчитать сумму с накоплением отдельно по входу и по выходу, потом UNION, потом сложить и затем уже выбор максимума.